# Unity with Facepunch.steamworks

Tags: unity-game-engine, steam, steamworks-api

I am using facepunch.steamworks with unity to connect my game with steam, however; i found an action called

```
 SteamMatchmaking.OnLobbyMemberKicked
```

Which mean there is a way to kick players out of the lobby but I cant find it.
is there  a possible way to kick players out of the lobby?

I have tried looking into the Lobby and Steammatchmaking but couldn't find anyway for kicking the players

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is interesting question because I was just looking for the same and was thinking I'm missing something obvious.

Thing is that not even Steam seems to actually have kicking players from lobbies implemented and Facepunch is "just" kind of C# wrapper around Steam API. See Steam API docs LobbyKicked_t for reference: ([Steamworks Documentation](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamMatchmaking))

In other words, likely best approach would be to send RPC to given client to invoke lobby leaving from client by calling `Lobby.Leave()` ([Facepunch wiki](https://wiki.facepunch.com/steamworks/Data.Lobby.Leave))

If anyone is aware of better option, I'm one ear, as I was hoping for some lobby kicking API, but seems not the case unfortunately

Hope this helps someone at least

Comment: Yeah I also thought of the same way of doing that but at first I wanted to check if I am missing something.
Thank you for your input

Comment: btw, just to be sure, note that Steam lobby is one thing, but you can still disconnect user from your host - if you're e.g. using Unity Netcode and Facepunch as a transport, there is a method "DisconnectRemoteClient()", which may actually help to achieve "kicking" better than sending RPC to run Lobby.Leave() - which is underlying Steam lobby, not the game "lobby" actually, kind of confusing sometimes - took me a while to wrap my head around this

Comment: DisconnectRemoteClient() will be called from the networkmanager itself when u disconnect a client with the DisconnectClient() method ,however ; the goal of this was to keep the lobby synced with the networkmanager clients which imo sending an RPC to make the client leave.

Comment: was just thinking of this as alternative way how to achieve it and then hook on OnClientDisconnectCallback to call leave Steam lobby as well. Anyway, good luck with your project ;)